# Controlling application access to different namespace using RBAC in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod, azure-aks

I am trying to find our the minimum privileges required for application to communicate in kubernetes for the below scenarios

1. App1 is in namespace 1 and app2 is in namespace 2
2. App1 is in cluster 1 anf app2 is in cluster 2

I have deployed an sample application in my cluster (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/release-1.2/examples/guestbook) in two different namespaces

However tough I associate these applications with service account have no privileges in respective namespaces , my php application is still able to reach redis application.
I was expecting it to throw an error , how are my applications functioning even after giving my service account no roles

Below is the role i associated with my service account

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Role
metadata:
 name: no-access-cr
rules:
- apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
  resources: [""] 
  verbs: [""]
```

Kindly assist!!!

Comment: `my php application is still able to reach redis application.` If you want to block network then please check NetworkPolicy. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/

Comment: The network is reachable but is there a way we can block this with RBAC

Comment: My question is , is there any minimal RBAC privileges required for communication between applications across namespaces or across clusters, that is what i was checking

Comment: can you use `networking.k8s.io/v1` in apiGroups and check?

Answer (score 1):

RBAC policies that you're applying to applications have nothing to do with networking (L3/L4) itself. They are related to L7 access to k8s APIs (kube-api server) and therefore access to k8s objects exposed via these APIs.

If you want to restrict access between the apps on networking level (L3/L4) you need to apply [network policies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/) Also depending on network plugin e.g. [calico policies](https://docs.projectcalico.org/reference/resources/networkpolicy) can be used.

Comment: Thank you , that really helped me understand , I am able control traffic with policies and controll access to api objects with RBAC